# How to write binary data into a file without invoking implementation-defined behavior?

Tags: c++, c

I am writing a program like this to write some bytes into a file.

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    char buffer[4] = {0, 0, 255, 255};
    std::ofstream f("foo.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
    f.write(buffer, sizeof buffer);
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine and gives me the expected result on my system.

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra signedness.cc
$ ./a.out
$ cat foo.txt
$ od -t x1 foo.txt 
0000000 00 00 ff ff
0000004
```

The equivalent C code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[4] = {0, 0, 255, 255};
    FILE *f = fopen("bar.txt", "wb");
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof *buffer, sizeof buffer, f);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

This program also works fine and gives the expected output on my system.

I want to know if the above way of writing bytes into a file is okay.

Section 4.7 (Integral conversions) of [C++ n3242.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) mentions in point 3:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

Section 6.3.1.3 (signed and unsigned integers) of [C n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) mentions in point 3:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

From these extracts, it seems like my program invokes implementation-defined behavior when I assign 255 as the last two bytes of `char buffer[4]` because 255 cannot be represented in `char` type. If I am right about this, then what would be the right way to write these four bytes into a file? Changing the type of `buffer` from `char` to `unsigned char` doesn't seem to help in C++ because ofstream's `write()` function still expects the first parameter to of type `const char*`.

Comment: Tip: In C++ you don't need to manually close a stream because it gets closed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Normally I would use uint8_t, defined in stdint.h

Comment: Make sure to open up these files in binary mode to avoid your '\n's getting ruined.

Comment: @TJD Not sure what your point is. 255 doesn't fit in signed char which is what this question is about.

Comment: @TJD How does `uint8_t` solve the problem? `ofstream`'s `write()` function accepts const char* as the first argument, so the `uint8_t` to `char` conversion is still subject to implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @LoneLearner C's `fwrite` takes a `const void*` as buffer, so using `unsigned char buffer[4] = { 0, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF };` makes it only depend on `CHAR_BIT == 8`, everything else is completely defined by the standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that `ofstream` is just a typedef for `std::basic_ofstream<char>`.

When you don't want things being treated as `char`, just use `std::basic_ofstream<unsigned char>` or `std::basic_ofstream<uint8_t>`.

Ultimately, though, iostreams are made for formatted I/O.  The API is horrible for binary I/O (since it doesn't take `void*`) and also incredibly slow.  Furthermore, every character is converted by a "facet", making it hard to guarantee 1:1 correspondence between input bytes and bytes on disk.  `basic_filebuf` is a little better, but not much.  Using `fopen` and `fwrite` is still a perfectly valid approach, even in C++.

Comment: Is `std::basic_ofstream` a part of the C++ standard library? I have always worked with `ofstream`, never with `basic_ofstream`, so I just want to confirm this.

Comment: @LoneLearner: Yes it is.  There is no class named `std::ofstream` at all, it's just a typedef like I said.  See section 27.9.1 in the standard.

Comment: `basic_ostream::write` does not use locales; it's strictly raw bytes.

Comment: @Pete: It uses the underlying `streambuf`, and `basic_filebuf` transforms data using facets.  Hence `basic_ostream::write` is affected also.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I hadn't realized that `basic_filebuf` carried around a locale. Nevertheless, if you don't ask for it, you don't pay for it; unless you imbue a locale, a sensible implementation won't grab a facet and use it.

Answer (score 0):

True, 255 can't be represented in a signed `char` type, but you're not assigning 255, you're assigning `FF`, which represents `-1`.

You want to be using a `uint8_t`, as defined in `stdint.h`, or at the very least use an `unsigned char`.

Comment: Not entirely sure about C++, but in C, `'\xff'` is the **`int`** 255, so there you have the implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: I think the OP knows this, but is concerned that this is apparently "implementation-defined".  However, I don't know of any architecture where that would be the case.  Pretty much everything I've seen in C exploits twos-complement arithmetic.

Comment: No sane implementation will treat this in a way you do not expect.

Comment: @Daniel, try `int test = '\xff'; printf("%d\n", test);`.  It does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @LoneLearner, the correct way to solve your problem is to use TJD's suggestion from his comment and use a `uint8_t` instead of a `char`.  At the very least, use an `unsigned char`.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt How does `uint8_t` solve the problem? `ofstream`'s `write()` function accepts `const char*` as the first argument, so the `uint8_t` to `char` conversion is still subject to implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt From my post: `Changing the type of buffer from char to unsigned char doesn't seem to help in C++ because ofstream's write() function still expects the first parameter to of type const char*.`

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt The `int test = '\xff'; printf("%d\n", test);` experiment you prints `-1`. Could you please explain why this is so? Don't character literals have `int` type in C? `printf("%d\n", sizeof test);` does print `4`.

Comment: `int test = '\xff';` from C99, the result is the same as `int test = (char) 0xFF;` which is implementation defined. *(6.4.4.4p10) "If an integer character constant contains a single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results when an object with type char whose value is that of the single character or escape sequence is converted to type int."*

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt "The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), _or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character_, is implementation-deﬁned." (emphasis mine). 255 does not map to a single-byte execution character usually (UTF-8). (But yes, whether the resulting `int` is 255 or not is again implementation defined.)

Comment: @DanielFischer & Karl Continuing my previous comment (I can no longer edit it). So the value of `'\xFF'` is not `(int) 255` but is actually `(int)(char) 0xFF`. If you compile the example `int test = '\xff'; printf("%d\n", test);` from Karl with `gcc` on x86/x64 and `-funsigned-char` you will get `255`.

Comment: @BenVoigt The question used `'\x00'` and `'\xff'` originally.

Answer (score -1):

"implementation-defined" is the language of the International Standard for C++, which is a quasi-legal document intended to cover every conceivable case.

So it could be running on a machine where char is 9 bits, hence it's inherent in the act of dealing with binary data and files that some aspects will be implementation-defined. By the letter of the Standard you have to study the documentation for each target machine and be sure that the behaviour you need is achieved in each case.

In the real world, every modern general-purpose CPU has 8-bit bytes and uses 2s-complement arithmetic, so there is nothing to worry about unless you are targeting a very specific situation.

Comment: Could you please answer my question in my post: How to write binary data like this without invoking implementation defined behavior?

Comment: `char` is required to be at least 8 bits in C and C++.

Comment: @PeteBecker: It's defined to be `CHAR_BITS`, and of course, `CHAR_BITS` must be >= 8.  I know you probably know this, just informational for the OP.

Comment: @LoneLearner: You can't avoid it, but you can write your code to take account of it using various constants and macros.